# htaccess - Image redirect issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect my image requests to the parent folder. So I try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/app/images/
RewriteRule ([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ ../images/$1 [R,L]
```

The trouble is, if the image request is say...

```
http://domain.com/app/en/images/123.jpg
```

.....it gets redirected to:

```
http://domain.com/en/images/123.jpg
```

instead of the desired...

```
http://domain.com/app/images/123.jpg
```

Comment: I would replace `../images/$1` with `/app/images/$1`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the rule you will need:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/app/images/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/[^/]*/([^/]*/[^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ /$1/$2 [R,L]
```